# Why isn't hybridization done in America?

Tags: teaching-lab

Warning: This is a question from my teacher.

In America hybridization isn't done, while in Europe it is done around the 10th grade. Is there any reason or advantage for doing(not doing) it as part of the school program?

Comment: you mean orbital hybridization like sp, sp2, sp3? Yes, this is taught in America.

Comment: Hybridization is taught in American high schools and colleges. I learned hybridization first in 10th grade. I think the main issue is that the quality of education varies greatly across America. Good schools will almost definitely teach hybridization in HS. After all, it's tested on the AP Chemistry Exam (a HS examination students can elect to take).

Comment: @MikhailTal You can't generalize the entire USA high school system.  Each state can be different.  Here is the Arkansas chemistry curriculum: http://www.arkansased.org/public/userfiles/Learning_Services/Curriculum%20and%20Instruction/Frameworks/Science/chemistry_9_12_2005_060508.pdf Hybridization is a required part of the curriculum.

Comment: AP student here, yes hybridization is taught.

Answer (score 4):

In Russia hybridization of carbon learns at the beginning of the 10th grade, before the main organic chemistry. Hybridization in the atoms of metals (complexes) are studied in grade 11. These two topics are difficult for students to understand. But they can be on the exams.

Advantages:

- It is easier to understand the spatial structure
- Explanation of coordination numbers in complexes
- For an explanation of the facts, when the atom forms a large number of bonds than the number of unpaired electrons in the ground state

Disadvantages:

- Difficult to understand
- There are many different theories
- Rarely used in the study follow-up program

Comment: I don't see how this is at all relevant to the question, it really doesn't answer it...

Comment: OPs asking about the US and Europe. If you have an idea about one country, wouldn't it be better if it was a comment? (I may be overreacting!)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MARamezani what's wrong with this answer? It's just fine. Russia is in Europe.

Comment: Indeed, but Russia *isn't* the whole Europe, is it? (The problem is with the question itself, honestly)

Comment: @Michael, I'd just like to point out that the initial question (when the comments were made) had much less information. The problem with it was that all it said was that they teach it in russia, which was not at all what the question was asking. Now that he has added advantages and disadvantages it is more suitable.